# Расщепление при встрече с другим алфавитом

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Скажем, у меня есть string:

```
欧珑 无极乌龙 Atelier Cologne Oolang Infini, 2010
```

Как я могу разбить его на массив из двух strings? `['欧珑 无极乌龙','Atelier Cologne Oolang Infini, 2010']`

Я старался:

```
names = re.split(r'([a-zA-Z]+)', names)
```

Но это дало:

```
names:  ['欧珑 无极乌龙 ', 'Atelier', ' ', 'Cologne', ' ', 'Oolang', ' ', 'Infini', ', 2010']
```

Comment: Интересно, если использовать `maxsplit=1`, то вернется массив на 3 элемента, а не на ожидываемых два: `names = re.split(r'([a-zA-Z]+)', names, maxsplit=1)`. А так, можно вручную соединить элементы, вот так: `if len(names) > 2:` `names = [names[0], ''.join(names[1:])]`

Comment: Ссылка на этот же вопрос на англоязычном SO [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64777908/splitting-when-meeting-another-alphabet).